# Pull data from big query to google sheet every Sunday at 11:59 pm for the last 21 days

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery

It needs to pull data from BigQuery to Google Sheets every Sunday at 11:59 pm for the last 21 days.

Here's the code I wrote to find out Sunday.

```
SELECT
 EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) AS year,
 week,
 name,
 parent_name,
 sum(total_sales) as total_revenue,
 title
 FROM partitioned_ts
WHERE
 id=14213
 and
 total_sales>0
 and
date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), 
             INTERVAL 
             IF( EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM CURRENT_DATE()) = 1, 
                 6, 
                 EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM CURRENT_DATE()) - 1) 
             DAY) - INTERVAL 21 DAY AND DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), 
             INTERVAL 
             IF( EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM CURRENT_DATE()) = 1, 
                 6, 
                 EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM CURRENT_DATE()) - 1) 
             DAY)
GROUP BY name, parent_name, week, year, title 
order by year DESC, week DESC, name
```

This query will process 85.31 GB when run. The old version of the query calculates the last 21 days from today

```
date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 21 DAY) AND CURRENT_DATE(
```

and this query processes only 1.6 GB when run. How should I write the query to process lower data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works:

date BETWEEN DATE_SUB((DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), WEEK(Saturday))), INTERVAL 21 DAY) AND (DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), WEEK(Saturday)))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to filter out rows older than 21 days would be:

```
DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), date, DAY) <= 21
```

If you need to reduce the scan size, the best approach is to partition the source table by date

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables#use_a_constant_filter_expression

Comment: Thanks @David Morals. I already partitioned the table by date. I want to get the 21 days of data prior to last Sunday. Something like this: DATE_DIFF(Sunday, date, DAY) <= 21. Which code should I use to calculate last Sunday?

Comment: This will always return the previous Sunday given the current date.

CURRENT_DATE() - (EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM CURRENT_DATE()) - 1)

If the current date is sunday, it will return the same day.